# in spark3.0.1,use DataFrame.foreachPartition,value foreach is not a member of Object

Tags: spark3

in idea

version:spark3.0.1,scala2.12.12,java1.8.0_212

my code:

```
val df=spark.range(10)

df.foreachParitition(rows=>{

     rows.foreach(.......)
})
```

error:

```
value foreach is not a member of Object

      rows.foreach(row=>{
```

if use spark2.4.7 and scala2.11,it is ok

So what's the problem?